# What's the required battery voltage within a DALLAS DS12C887+ RTC?

Tags: hardware

I am having some difficulty getting a board that has a Dallas Real Time Clock DS12C887+ to behave. Not sure if the problem is the RTC or not but am in the investigative stage and got the cross hairs focussed on it right now.

The DS12C887+ has an onboard (and inaccesible) battery that is molded in. My suspicion is/was that the battery in it is flat. I have filed two slots in the side of the RTC and exposed the battery terminals. I get 2.92V from the RTC (using a Fluke 87 III which i think is fairly accurate). Would this be sufficient voltage to reliably operate the RTC or is it a bit too low. I can piggyback a Li-Ion battery (CR2030 or equivalent 3V which actually reads 3.2v) onto the RTC by gluing a button battery holder in place and soldering a couple of pigtails to the terminals i have exposed and then cutting the existing battery out of circuit.

The manufacturers datasheet for the RTC can be found by searching "DS12885-DS12C887A.pdf". Does anyone know if 2.9V is enough to keep the RTC running reliably?

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you could add any information about the environment. What computer, what board, what problem you try to fix  *at the computer*. As it stands now, this question is rather about the battery part, thus more appropriate for [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) than here.

Comment: looks like a EE.SE question to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's purely an electronics question, so better suited to EE.SE

Answer (score 4):

2.9V seems like more than enough to keep it running. If you look into the data sheet you'll notice that a switch over to battery only happens below 3V.

But there's a simple solution: **Buy a new one.** They are about 5-10 EUR (~5-15 USD) depending on the shop you order from.

The DS12C887 real-time clocks is a rather new development (to replace DS1287) thus ready available. No need to file holes and tinker with the innards - unless your interest is the structure of this modern device - but that would be OT here on RC.SE, wouldn't it?